# How do I get to the Upper Level to Disable the Venting of the Hangar?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am about to attack Cerberus headquarters. EDI tells me to access a console in the upper level, but I don't see how to get there. And since it's time-critical I've already got a few mission overdue to this.

How do I access the console on the upper level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a ladder to the left side of the hanger, where a sniper will take up a defensive position when you're beginning your attack.

[image: ladder leading to control room]

Going up the ladder will take you to the first control, and then you'll need to make your way through that room and around the upper level to the second control room to complete the process.